# simplest method for overloading constructors

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I need a class (very simple) with two kinds of constructors: in one case I allocate a plain c-array, in the other its a std::vector. The parameters of the constructors are in both cases the same. What is the appropriate way to make them distinct without having to add an pseudo-parameter to one of them?

Edit: I wonder if the following solution is reasonable in some cases:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int v>
struct data_container
{
    enum { value = v };
};

typedef data_container<0> c_array;
typedef data_container<1> MatrixXd_type;

/*
 * =====================================================================================
 *        Class:  fooC
 * =====================================================================================
 */
class fooC
{
public:

    fooC (c_array) {
        cout<<"c_array"<<endl;
    };
    fooC (MatrixXd_type) {
        cout<<"MatrixXd_type"<<endl;
    };


private:
    fooC();

}; /* -----  end of class fooC  ----- */

int main() {
    c_array type1;
    MatrixXd_type type2;
    fooC obj_foo1(type1);
    fooC obj_foo2(type2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you allocate the array? As a member or as a local object to the constructor?

Comment: I tried to ask very general, since I had this problem already several times and in most cases I added an additional parameter. The allocation is as a member.

Comment: To me, that sounds like you need two classes, as opposed to two constructors of one class. Having said that, an option is to make the constructor private and instead use static create functions such as `static my_class create_with_vector(...)` and `static my_class create_with_array(...)`.

Comment: @BartvanNierop: I'll follow your hint, it is in my case the simplest choise!

Comment: would it be ok to add in both constructors a parameter which would be of a type generated by
template <int v>
struct Int2Type
{
enum { value = v };
};
as proposed by Alexandrescu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea that you have two different types of data in your class really means that you have 2 child classes sharing (perhaps) some base class functionality.

That's how you should approach this: yes have two different constructors, one on each child class. Each child class holds data appropriate to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with a template class:

```
template<class Container>
class klass {
private:
    Container container;
public:
    // ...
};
```

so that you could call:

```
klass<std::array<int, 10>> x;
klass<std::vector<int>> y;
```

But an even better solution would be to just hide the implementation and just use `std::vector`:

```
class klass {
private:
    std::vector<int> container;
public:
    // ...
};
```